# getting variable by concat showing name not showing value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a variable inside for loop but getting name of variable not value.

```
var c1 = ['2', '4', '7', '5']
```

trying to get it here:

```
var a = 1;

console.log('c'+a);
```

It shows `c1` instead of array.

Help me to undestand this

Comment: You could do `window['c1']`. But you're probably better keeping an array of arrays such that you can do `c[1]` or in your example `c[a-1]`

Comment: "c" here is a string and "a" is an integer. Not a variable name. that's why it comes as c1. Do console.log(c1);

Comment: Instead of creating an array called `c1`, create an object called `c` that contains the key `1`, then you can call c[a].

Answer (score 1):

everithing belong to window

```js
var c1 = ['2', '4', '7', '5']
var a = 1;

console.log('window.c1 => ',window['c'+a]);  // but this is really bad code

// prefer to do :

var data = {  c1 : ['2', '4', '7', '5'] }

console.log('data.c1 => ', data['c'+a] );
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw your array is 'c1',not 'c';
so,try this:

`console.log(c1[a])`

Comment: The OP wants to print the array, not an element from the array

Comment: I thought I made a mistake.Another answer shows the result.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show `c1` you need use eval, if `'c' + 1` it only show string 'c1' not variable c1

```
var c1 = ['2', '4', '7', '5']

var a = 1;

console.log(eval('c'+a));
```

```js
var c1 = ['2', '4', '7', '5']

var a = 1;

console.log(eval('c'+a));
```

Comment: Using eval is highly discouraged! If you find yourself having to use eval, try finding another way!